# Remove the white outer border in ant design icons

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

[image]

I used this code to set the thickness of ant design icon but as you can see in the image, there is white outer border. Can anyone help me to remove this white outer border while keeping the thickness thinner?

My code looks like

```
import { PlusCircleOutlined} from "@ant-design/icons";
    <PlusCircleOutlined
                     
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "54px",
                        color: "#408021",
                        stroke:"white",
                        strokeWidth:"40"
                      }}
                    />
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `strokeWidth` attribute? The outer white border is caused by the property being set, so it seems obvious to me. Am I missing the point of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `stroke` and `strokeWidth`:

```
import { PlusCircleOutlined} from "@ant-design/icons";
<PlusCircleOutlined
                 
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "54px",
                    color: "#408021"
                  }}
                />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I have to keep the thickness as current. If I remove the stroke property, the circle becomes thicker and that's not what i want.

Comment: please add an example of what you wish and a link for your work so I can help you solve this